# How to add Ads in flutter web (Google Adsense)

Tags: flutter, dart, ads, adsense

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-3610741546045128"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- demoAD -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3610741546045128"
     data-ad-slot="4603998330"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I'm looking at a way to insert AdSense ads to a mobile website built in flutter-web
I got the above code from the google AdSense console, where to place it, and how to configure it?

Comment: I think this package is what you are searching for: https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

Comment: It is only for android and IOS, I want to configure in web!

Comment: I see, maybe this plugin suits better you needs: https://pub.dev/packages/admanager_web

Comment: @LelilolZH I tried this package, and it is not working!

Answer (score 0):

google_mobile_ads is only for android and ios

---

not for the web

---

so this is impossible